# Having trouble inserting Javascript select onchange function for Google Visualization

Tags: javascript, select, google-visualization, onchange

I'm newbie in JS programming. I want to make a select option where I can change the chart type e.g. from line to bar. The data source comes from Google Spreadsheet. The JS code is as follow:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>
  Select Chart Type
</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:  ['linechart',corechart','barchart', 'columnchart']});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var graphview;

function init() {
graphview = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
dataSourceUrl: 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/tq?tq=select%20A,B......etc
containerId: 'visualization1', chartType: 'LineChart'


graphview.draw();
}   


google.setOnLoadCallback(init);
}
</script>
</head>
<body> 
<div id="panelgraph", width="600", height="200">
</body>
</html>
```

The options are as follow:

```
<select id="graphbox" name="graphbox"  onChange="getChart()">
<option value="Line">Line Chart </option>
<option value="Bar">Bar Chart</option>
<option value="Core">Area Chart</option>
<option value="Column">Column Chart</option>                                                                    
</select>
```

I try to make a function, but was not sure how and where to insert them:

```
var mygraphbox = document.getElementById("graphbox"); 
var myinsertgraphhere = document.getElementById("panelgraph");      
mygraphbox.onchange =function()
```

I follow some example of how to make onchange select option function. But when I want to apply it for my case (e.g. using if-else and chart the map) I have  troubles. Please help me  how to formulate it and how to inserting it in the JS block.

Thank you in advance,
Dian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick solution; change your javascript to this:

```
function init () {
    var graphview = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        chartType: 'LineChart',
        containerId: 'visualization1',
        dataSourceUrl: 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/tq?key=<key>&gid=0',
        options: {
            // chart options
        },
        query: 'select a, b, c'
    });

    graphview.draw();

    function changeHandler () {
        graphview.setChartType(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);
        graphview.draw();
    }

    var mygraphbox = document.querySelector("#graphbox");
    if (typeof(window.addEventListener) == 'function') {
        mygraphbox.addEventListener('change', changeHandler, false);
    }
    else if (typeof(window.attachEvent) == 'function') {
        mygraphbox.attachEvent('onchange', changeHandler);
    }
}

google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:  ['corechart'], callback: init});
```

and change the select box like this:

```
<select id="graphbox">
    <option value="LineChart">Line Chart </option>
    <option value="BarChart">Bar Chart</option>
    <option value="AreaChart">Area Chart</option>
    <option value="ColumnChart">Column Chart</option>                                                                    
</select>
```

With this, you can change the chart type without resubmitting the query.

Comment: thanks for the answer and I tried it. I get this message "Invalid query Column [b] does not exist in table". My intention with the code is that I want to use the same data source, but users can change the chart type. For example the display will change to be bar chart when a user selects Bar Chart.

Comment: This could should do that.  Can you post the spreadsheet URL and query string you are using so I can test it?

Comment: I still uses "fake data" to test if this thing works. Here the query:     dataSourceUrl: 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/tq?tq=select%20A,B,C,D%20order%20by%20A%20desc%20limit%2040&key=0AqRAkGgWZtIXdGZUdHBIdlU0Z1pmM3g3MXRrWTVHQ3c'

Comment: I repost the query      dataSourceUrl: 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/tq?tq=select%20A,B,C,D%20order%20by%20A%20desc%20limit%2040&key=0AqRAkGgWZtIXdGZUdHBIdlU0Z1pmM3g3MXRrWTVHQ3c'

Comment: I made a jsfiddle based on that URL and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/SyxpM/

Comment: Wow yes, thanks a lot @asgallant--I tried many different ways and was not work. Your code works well. Then I know I should remove the following line: query: 'select a, b, c, d'

Comment: You can either remove the `query` parameter, or you can write your select statement there and remove the `tq=select...` part from your query URL.  See http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/SyxpM/1/ as an alternative